# GitLab pipeline fail: Unknown option: -c

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, continuous-deployment

I have created a pipeline to run a series of jobs that deploy my application to a sandbox environment automatically. My configuration of `.gitlab-ci.yml` is:

```
stages:
  - pull
  - build

pull-code-job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd /usr/share/nginx/html
    - git pull http://myuser:mypassword@mydomain.com/user/my-app.git master

build-code-job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run alpha
```

When I view the pipelines log, I always find that they have failed:

```
Unknown option: -c
```

[image: All output of pipeline]

I no call `git -c`.

My version os GitLab CE is 12.0.3 and the version of git that use runners is 1.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every job that you define, the code associated with the pipeline will always be fetched or cloned into the job environment before any of your script, before_script, or after_script sections are run. If you job should be running against the code in the repository, you don't have to `git clone` or `git pull` at all; it will happen automatically for you. The output you're seeing in the job is from this automatic fetch.

If you need to, you can disable the automatic fetch using the `GIT_STRATEGY` variable set to none:

```
pull-code-job:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - cd /usr/share/nginx/html
    - git pull http://myuser:mypassword@mydomain.com/user/my-app.git master
```

For this job, the repository will not be fetched/cloned from Gitlab. This is useful if you have another job in your pipeline that pulls down your code, then builds an artifact like npm dependencies, compiled binaries from the source code, etc.

Since you're using the `shell` executor, the job is running directly on the host the runner is on (as opposed to within a Docker container). Looking at the `git usage` output, there doesn't appear to be a `-c` option for that git version. Try upgrading `git` on the host where your `gitlab-runner` ALPHA is running and run your pipeline again.

Comment: Ok, I understand how it works, thanks Adam. With GIT_STRATEGY the error does not appear. Do you know with which user the runner executes the shell commands? I get a permission denied error when pull manually:
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: unable to unlink old '.gitlab-ci.yml' (Permission denied)
Updating 0d43c79..f8e578b

Comment: The user is gitlab-runner and permission denied error is solved with: chmod -R g+w ./html